# C# Filter differences from a path

Tags: c#, substring

`DirectoryPath` = *C:\Pics*

`filePath` = *C:\Pics\Dogs\dog.PNG*

`newPath` should be: *Dogs\dog.PNG*

---

How do I get the `newPath`?
My code snippet is not right

---

```
string directoryPath = "C:\\Pics";
string filePath = "C:\\Pics\\Dogs\\dog.PNG";

if (!directoryPath.EndsWith("\\"))
   directoryPath = directoryPath + "\\";

string newPath = filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf(directoryPath) + 1);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/208223). Are you sure you want the difference of the strings and not the relative path?

Comment: `LastIndexOf` and `IndexOf` return the index where the substring starts, not where it ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `int` Index you get from `LastIndexOf()` will always starts with the rightmost value, in your case 0. You have also to add the `String.Lenght` for this.

```
if (filePath.StartsWith(directoryPath))
{
    string newPath =
       filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf(directoryPath) + directoryPath.Length + 1);
}
```

Comment: You should check that the start of the original file path does match the directory path.

Comment: With this code, you could not use `newpath` outside your `if` :)

Comment: @Pikoh I don't want to make it OP too easy ;)

Comment: @Smartis ok ok,fair enough

Answer (score 2):

Could you append a backslash to the directory path & then in the filepath replace the directory path with an empty string

```
newPath = filePath.Replace(DirectoryPath + @"\", string.Empty);
```

If the directoryPath does not match the start of the filePath, then newPath will be unchanged.

I did post this before you edited your code to show the conditional adding of the backslash - so that can be removed in the above code.

Answer (score 1):

I would first check if `filePath` contains `DirectoryPath`,so i'd do something like this:

```
 var newPath=filePath.Contains(DirectoryPath)?filePath.Substring(DirectoryPath.Length + 1)
                                             :filePath;
```

Or even better,using `StartsWith`

```
var newPath=filePath.StartsWith(DirectoryPath)?filePath.Substring(DirectoryPath.Length + 1)
                                             :filePath;
```